# -1103 Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1103 "resource exceeds maximum size" iOS 13

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, ios13

We are facing the following networking error when the response is somehow large(14kb) on iOS 13.

`[-1103] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1103 "resource exceeds maximum size"`

As we are using Alamofire, this problem is treated as error result which breaks our treatments of the results.

The strange thing is that if we use NSURLSession directly, though this error is still seen from logging, we don't actually receive it in the callback of

```
session.dataTask(with: request) { value, response, error in ... }
```

So the result can treated correctly.

This problem is never seen before. Anyone has got some idea on that ?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Using currently macOs 10.15 beta 3 and iOS 13 beta 3. Not sure if it has something to do with the betas

Comment: ios13 prevents GET requests to have a body. if your backend allows it, use a POST method

Comment: But it works perfectly fine with live ios13, issues comes when you are developing with xcode 11 ios 13.

Comment: @MoinShirazi the issue appears only when you compile with iOS 13+ sdk

Answer (score 184, accepted):

With the help of the Slack community, we find the answer is that 
`on iOS13, it is not allowed to add a body in GET request.` To make it work again, we can either switch to a POST/PUT request or add body value via url parameters of the GET request.

Comment: thanks, In which Slack community you are discussing about, I had the same issue. Also I am facing another issue in iOS 13 with FileManager. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081267/nscocoaerrordomain-code-257-operation-not-permitted-filemanager-attributesofit

Comment: My request is with method GET and sending data : {}, but don't works; avoid sending an object and it worked, thanks!!

Comment: Excellent to find this. Had a similar problem with a program I’m developing on macOS 13.4. Same problem as iOS, same resolution by switching to a POST request.

Answer (score 20):

Pass query parameters in `GET` request like the following:

```
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "param": value
]
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString)
```

Comment: It helps. But why? Please explain

Answer (score 15):

I have face same issue and find out the solution.

**You can't pass parameter in body while using GET.**

Either use POST method if API support or pass it in URL like below.

> **AnyURL?Parameter=Value&Parameter=Value**

Comment: straight to the point... save my day :)

Answer (score 11):

Finally found the answer. For GET services I was trying to add an httpBody. Something like this:

```
do {
    request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: .prettyPrinted)
} catch let error {
    errorCompletion(error)
    return
}
```

The solution was just to add an if to avoid that chunk of code if httpMethod is a GET. Seems like an iOS 13 new behavior and the error message given by Swift definitely not helps at all

Comment: but how will you pass the parameters then?

Comment: Thread 1: "*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: Invalid top-level type in JSON write"

Answer (score 8):

**Alamofire: You should try this!**

```
Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.queryString)
```

Just avoid the `httpBody` for the `GET` API request.

```
if requestType != .get{
     request.httpBody = data
}
```

### OR

**For `GET` request append parameter into URL instead of the `HTTP body`**

Use the below extension to create a query parameter from the dictionary.

```
extension NSObject {
    func buildQueryString(fromDictionary parameters: [String:String]) -> String {
        var urlVars = [String]()
        for (var k, var v) in parameters {
            let characters = (CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed as NSCharacterSet).mutableCopy() as! NSMutableCharacterSet
            characters.removeCharacters(in: "&")
            v = v.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characters as CharacterSet)!
            k = k.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: characters as CharacterSet)!
            urlVars += [k + "=" + "\(v)"]
        }
        
        return (!urlVars.isEmpty ? "?" : "") + urlVars.joined(separator: "&")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I used default url encoding instead of default json encoding and it's worked for me.

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get, parameters: param, encoding: URLEncoding.default)
```

### OR

If you using URLRequestConvertible

```
enum NetworkRouter: URLRequestConvertible {

    case someCase(lang:String)

    var method: HTTPMethod {
        return .get
    }

    var parameters: Parameters? {
        switch self {
        case .someCase(let param):
            return ["lang": param.lang]
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    var url: URL {
        switch self {
        case .someCase(let param):
            return URL(string: Constants.baseURL + Constants.endPoint)!
        default:
            return URL(string: Constants.baseURL)!
        }
    }

    var encoding: ParameterEncoding {
        return URLEncoding.default
    }

    func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue
        return try encoding.encode(urlRequest, with: parameters)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I got that issue because i pass empty parameters in Alamofire when send get request. So, instead of sending empty parameters i simply replace it for nil.

Answer (score 2):

My fix is I only set `.parameters` to nil, then everything works fine. Because in Swift it still initialize the value of `.parameters`.

`self.request.parameters = nil`

Answer (score 1):

Here you might have missing the method of the URL request that you are passing to data task. You have to add POST/PUT/DELETE to the URL request method parameter like below.

```
var request: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: SOME_VALID_URL) 
request.body = SOME_VALID_DATA_IN_BYTES
request.method = "post" --> You are missing this.
```

Answer (score 0):

I only see this issue when I build with Xcode 11. If I revert back to Xcode 10.3 I do not have the same issue anymore. While not a forever fix, if you're needing to push out code you can revert until you have time to fix it.