# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 when trying to access "My Photo Stream" media in iOS 13

Tags: ios13

In iOS 13, I get an error when I try to access to "My Photo Stream" media, which doesn't exist in device.

> Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 "ファイル“IMG_0010.JPG”を表示するためのアクセス権がないため、開けませんでした。" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/var/mobile/Media/PhotoStreamsData/8281221100/100APPLE/IMG_0010.JPG, NSUnderlyingError=0x283452820 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=1 "Operation not permitted"}}

But in iOS 12 and earlier, I don't get the error.

My actual code is like below.

```c
// asset is Photo Stream media.

PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *editOptions = [PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions new];
editOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
editOptions.progressHandler = ^void(double progress, BOOL *stop) {};

[asset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions
                           completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

    NSError *error;
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL
                                         options:(NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe)
                                           error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", data); // "Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257"
```

I found some people who are struggling with similar issues.
[NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=257 file couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it : FileManager attributesOfItem returns nil in iOS13](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58081267/nscocoaerrordomain-code-257-file-couldn-t-be-opened-because-you-don-t-have-permi)

I know Apple is putting so much effort into privacy.

So anything changed around it? And I'd like to know the way to solve my problem.